# Seqeulize custom validator Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, es6-promise

Here's the documentation for validators: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html . It says to throw an error if it fails

Say I have a users table and I only want max 500 users to be added, so I create a validator:

```
{
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'users',
    validate: {
      limitUsers: async function(x) {
          const count = await sequelize.models.User.count({...});
          if (count > 500) {
            throw new Error(
              `blah blah`,
             );
          }
        }
      },
    },
  },
```

When I create a user, it's part of a transaction, but the call looks something like

```
 try {

    const user = await user.create(
      {
       ...
      },
      { transaction },
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Handle error here');
    ....
  }
```

For some reason the catch is not throwing the error thrown in the validator, and It's just throwing a 500, without hitting the catch. Why is this happening? Do I just not understand how promises work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that validators must be synchronous so that's why sequelize nor awaits async validators neither catches rejects from them.

A possible reason might be that validators must be fast and don't use queries (otherwise there will be a question about passing a transaction to a validator).

Complex async validations should be outside models and should be executed before calling any data modifying operations.